# Looping through each cell in a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I was writing a program for deleting a row in a Selection with Empty Cell. I wrote the code and it worked well but it have a deficiency.

Code Is:

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Num As Integer
    Num = Selection.Cells.Count
    'MsgBox ("Num of Cells " & Num)
     Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    If (IsEmpty(ActiveCell)) Then
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    For i = 1 To Num
        If (IsEmpty(ActiveCell)) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
            Num = Num - 1
            On Error GoTo Last
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Next

Last:
    Exit
```

Now I was trying to rewrite the code with looping the cell in Range instead of above For loop:

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Num As Integer
    Dim myRange As Range
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Set myRange = Selection.Cells
        For Each myRange In Selection
        If (IsEmpty(myRange)) Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
            On Error GoTo Last
        Else
            'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Next myRange

Last:
    Exit
```

This piece of code is not working Properly. Kindly put your Suggestions and rectify the Code

Comment: why not just start at the bottom and work numerically up by row number like all good 'delete if blank' code?

Comment: i am beginner to Excel VBA prob...can you modify the code so that i will come to know the logic and code..please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Selection) > 0 Then Intersect(Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow, Selection.Columns(1)).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: OP apparently wants to delete only the cells in selection, probably with shift:=xlup.

Comment: Worked fine thanks...As i am beginner to VBA prob...Can u modify my code ...as i want to learn how would my code work ...

Answer (score 0):

Speciealcells seems to be easy to use.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Set rngDB = Selection

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDB = rngDB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        rngDB.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that avoids relying on `Selection` and `Select`.

You can use a `InputBox` to determine the range. This will allow you to properly qualify all of your ranges/worksheets. You can then loop through the selected range and determine if the rows should be deleted (if blank).

At the end, delete all the rows at once. On larger operations, this will be much faster since you will only have 1 instance of deletion rather continuously deleting rows in the loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Blanks()

Dim MyRange As Range, MyCell As Range, DeleteMe As Range
Set MyRange = Application.InputBox("Select Range", Type:=8)

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If MyCell = "" Then
        If DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = MyCell
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, MyCell)
        End If
    End If
Next MyCell

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```